# Grafana dashboard separate variables for different panels?

Tags: openshift, prometheus, grafana, dashboard

I'm fairly new at creating Grafana dashboards. Using Prometheus data source (Red Hat Openshift). Creating a dashboard with two panels.

Is there a way to create separate variables for each of the panels?  Example if I want one panel to select drop down for 'namespace' and the other panel to have a drop down for 'node'.  Is this possible? I've been hacking on this for a bit with no success.

I welcome any inputs from the community.  Thanks.

Tried adding two variables to the dashboard and it did not work as expected.

Comment: In what way does it "did not work as expected"? You can add two different variables and use one per panel, no problem. There is no obligation for you to use all variables in each and every panel.

Answer (score 1):

Add two variables to the dashboard and just use the one you need in each panel. In this way, the selection of one variable in a panel does nos affect the other panel